# When is "mod $n$" a congruence relation on the lattice $(\Bbb N,\gcd,\text{lcm})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, lattice-orders

For which $n\in \Bbb N$,

$$a\equiv b,a'\equiv b'\quad \text{implies} \quad \gcd(a,a')\equiv \gcd(b,b'), 
\text{lcm}(a,a')\equiv \text{lcm}(b,b')$$
all mod $n$.

> For $n=2$ it is true.

Comment: Did you devise this question? If not, what is its source?

Comment: I do not know any existing written source.

Comment: But did you devise it or did someone else? If the latter, it is possible that the intended meaning is different from that in the given answer.

Comment: Could you please reveal the source?

Comment: for congruences see this http://books.google.com/books?id=6XJX5-zCoIQC&pg=PA36

Comment: I know that. My point is that the problem may have been misinterpreted from the source. Without knowing the source I cannot confirm or deny that.

Comment: The question is clear. This question arose in a classroom. I said it does not seem to be true. They considered mod 2 and it was true. However no written source.

Comment: @MathGems: also thanks for your good answers for some of my previous questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is trivially true when $n=1$, and easily verified to be true when $n=2$. Consider $n \geq 3$. Consider

\begin{equation}
1 \equiv (n-1)^2 \pmod{n}, n-1 \equiv n-1 \pmod{n} \\
\gcd(1, n-1)=1 \not \equiv -1 \equiv \gcd((n-1)^2, n-1) \pmod{n}
\end{equation}

Therefore it is only true for $n=1, 2$.